# what is the grub customizer app and how is it used to handle different operating systems?

Tags: grub2

I do not understand what exactly Grub customizer is. I have heard about it in the context of managing different operating systems. Can somebody kindly explain to me how it is used along with the appropriate instructions for it?

Answer (score 1):

**Grub Customizer** is a graphical interface to configure the **GRUB2/BURG** settings and menuentries.

**Features**:

- move, remove or rename menuentries (they stey updatable by update-grub)
- edit the contents of menuentries or create new ones (internally it edits the 40_custom)
- support for GRUB2 and BURG
- reinstallation of the bootloader to MBR
- settings like default operating system, kernel params, background image and text colors etc.
- changing the installed operating system by running on a live cd